# Проблема с выводом данных из БД в виде плитки JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, jdbc, arraylist

Есть jsp страница - home.jsp. Там есть два блока: один добавляет данные в базу данных(это работает), а второй получает данные из базы данных и выводит в виде плитки(ul -> li). Получать данные он должен при авторизации и после добавления новых данных в первом блоке.

Когда я захожу в аккаунт мне пишет такую ошибку(срабатывает переадресация(:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Home] in context with path [/Site] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /home.jsp at line 70

67:                         <%
68:                             ArrayList<Link> links = (ArrayList<Link>)request.getAttribute("links");
69:                                 
70:                                 for(Link link: links)
71:                                 {
72:                                     System.out.println(link.link.toString());
73:                                     //out.println(link.link.toString());


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:199)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Понять почему так происходит не могу. Проверял в отладчике и данные в ArrayList links есть и данные в Link link тоже.

home.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    String login = null;
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    for(Cookie cookie: cookies) {
        //out.println(cookies.length);
        if(cookie.getName().equals("login")) {
            login = cookie.getValue();
        } 
    }
    if(login == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("index");
    }
    request.setAttribute("login", login);
%>    

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>YOUR LINKS - Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&subset=latin,cyrillic,cyrillic-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:600,700&subset=latin,vietnamese,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  </head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <%@include file="header.jsp" %>
            <form action="Logout" method="post"><button type="submit" class="logoutBtn">Logout</button></form>
            <div class="addLink">
                    <form action="AddLink" method="post">
                        <div class="topForm">
                            <span id="Info">
                             <%
                                Object infoHome = request.getAttribute("InfoHome");
                                if (infoHome != null) {
                                    out.append(infoHome.toString());
                                }
                             %>
                            </span>
                            <p class="linkP">Link<span class="req">*</span></p>
                            <input type="text" required placeholder="Paste your link" name="link"/> 
                            <p class="titleP" style="width: 4%; margin-left: 35px;">Title</p>
                            <input style="width: 22%;" type="text" placeholder="Title"  name="title"/> 
                        </div>
                        <p class="descrP">Description</p>
                        <textarea rows="4" cols="10" placeholder="Enter description for a link" name="descr"></textarea>
                        <button type="submit" class="buttonAdd">Add Link</button>
                    </form>
            </div>
            <div class="links">
                <p>Saved links</p>
                <div class="bar">
                    <ul>
                        <%@ page import="java.*" %>
                        <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
                        <%@ page import="ru.tsyklop.site.Link" %>

                        <%
                            ArrayList<Link> links = (ArrayList<Link>)request.getAttribute("links");

                                for(Link link: links)
                                {
                                    System.out.println(link.link.toString());
                                    //out.println(link.link.toString());
                        %>
                                    <li class="link"><a href="<%= link.link.toString() %>"><%= link.title.toString() %></a></li>
                        <%
                                }   
                        %>

                        <%--<c:forEach items="${links}" var="current">
                            <li class="link"><a href="${current.link}">${current.title}</a></li>
                        </c:forEach> --%>

                        <!--<li class="link"><a>Title</a></li>
                        <li class="link"><a>Title</a></li>
                        <li class="link"><a>Title</a></li>
                        <li class="link"><a>Title</a></li>
                        <li class="link"><a>Title</a></li>
                        <li class="link"><a>Title</a></li>
                        <li class="link"><a>Title</a></li>-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <%@include file="footer.jsp" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Выявленная проблема:** 
При первой авторизации мы получаем данные с БД. Но куки, которые должны создаться при авторизации не создавались. В home.jsp есть проверка куков - соответственно проверка не проходила так как куков нет. Нас переадресовывало на index.jsp. И тут куки появлялись и нас переадресовывает на home.jsp но у нас уже нет тех данных которые мы достали первый раз. Вот и вылазит ошибка.

**Решение:**

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("login", Login);
            cookie.setMaxAge(60*20);
            response.addCookie(cookie);
            cookie.setPath("/"); 
            cookie.setDomain("localhost");  
            request.setAttribute("links", connect.linkArr);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home");
            dispatcher.include(request,response);
```

В файле авторизации, где создаём куки добавляем 
**cookie.setPath("/"); cookie.setDomain("localhost");** после строки **response.addCookie(cookie);**
И. Мы изменяем dispatcher.
У меня так работает!.

Comment: **так работает только при первой авторизации!**

**Если закрыть вкладку и открыть то напишет ошибку!**

**Нужна помощь!**